# Is it a good practice to store head tag information in a separate file and later include it?

Tags: php, html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/homepage.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navmenu.css"/>
    <!-- more css here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navmenu.js"></script>
    <!-- more js here -->
</head>
```

i have all of that external css and javascripts inside the `<head></head>` tag in all of my pages and all of that are important in all pages.. is it appropriate to put all of that in a separate file and just include that using php? so if i want to make some changes on those externals it would be easy for me,  because it will affect all my pages..  i just want to know if it is a good practice.. **thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. But why stop there? Ideally you should have all of your repetitive markup in a single file.

There are numerous approaches to sharing common markup in PHP, but the simplest way is to have a global "Top.php" and "Bottom.php" files, like so:

In Top.php:

```
 <html>
 <head>
      <title><?php echo $pagetitle; ?></title>
      <!-- your <meta /> elements go here -->
 </head>
 <body>
      <!-- common page elements go here -->
```

In Bottom.php:

```
 </body>
 </html> <!-- This ensures all of the common markup is closed -->
```

Then for each page, do this:

```
 <?php $pageTitle = "This page's title";
 require("Top.php"); ?>
 <!-- put your per-page markup and PHP code here -->
 <?php require("Bottom.php"); ?>
```

Simples.

Now how I use `require()` instead of `include()`. The require function is more strict and basically ensures that the included files exist. I think it's better for an application to visibly break than to fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

Save your snippets to separate files and then include() them.

And yes, it is a good practice, but much better is to use some decent templating system.
Look at Latte templating system from [Nette Framework](http://doc.nette.org/en/templating)

Answer (score 0):

Sure It is good practice. Put this in a separate PHP script ie head.php then include in all other  pages using

```
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question straight forwardly.

YES! It is a good practice.

A good programmer will not re-code everything at every page (one of the necessity lead to the invention of CLASS). So. Carry on! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's appropriate to pull common data like that into separate files. The question really is, now that it's in a separate file, what do you do with it?

You have at least four options.

- server-side (host-based) include files
- php `include` statement
- php `require` or `require_once` statement
- make

Server-side includes are generally believed to hurt performance, especially on low-cost (oversold?) shared web hosting servers.   There are other issues.

[The `include` and the `require` statements in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) differ mainly in how they respond to missing files. The `include` statement produces a warning; `require` produces a fatal error.

The make utility is less commonly used, but it's very useful. Using make, you can include any file within another file, producing output that has static content when it makes sense to have static content, and dynamic content when it makes sense to have dynamic content.

For information like you're talking about, you could use make to produce files in which the stylesheets and javascript references are static (so there's no performance hit), with all the maintainability of a single source file.  A properly built makefile guarantees that any change to the stylesheet/javascript file will be incorporated in the next build.

Other text utilities can do some of the same things, especially if you're *only* talking about file inclusion. (m4, for example.)